# Bluetooth communication with external device

Tags: iphone, linux, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am beginning a project where I need to make an embedded device running Linux communicate with an iPhone, using Bluetooth.
The app need only be able to send and receive files (at most ~100KB) between the device and the iPhone. The rest of the functionality can be added later.

I'm still in the phase of trying to find an appropriate technical solution to the problem. So far I've come to couple of conclusions.

Since the device is probably not MFi certified, the only way to communicate with it is using BT 4.0 (LE). Thus the app will only work on iPhone 4S and will have to be implemented using CoreBluetooth API. Am I correct?

But what is required on the device side? Say that the device implements the standard BlueZ BT stack and supports BT 4.0.

How do I retrieve files from the Linux filesystem and make them transfer to my iPhone? Is there a suitable Bluetooth profile or will I have to create my own?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me like any of the currently standardized profiles will serve your needs ([see here](http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/GATT-Specification-Documents.aspx)). So at the moment rolling your own profile seems to be the most likely solution. There might be others working on similar profiles though (it seems like a common enough use case) so maybe a standard solution will evolve when the new stack has matured a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input. May anyone develop their own profile, or does it have to be standardized? I don't know anything about how to implement an LE profile, do you know what skills and time it takes?

Comment: I've been researching this a bit myself - I found this presentation that gives a bit of an overview: http://www.bluegiga.com/files/bluegiga/Bluetooth_LE/Profile_development_BLE.pdf

It looks to me like anyone can make their own, but obviously a standardized one would allow for interoperability. It looks like it's a manageable amount of work, but it does require you to get into the details of how profiles work. (from what I've read about BTLE before a lot of the really low-level stuff is handled at a lower level than the profile, but it's not just a walk in the park either)

Comment: It seems very simple to define a new LE profile, but how do we actually implement it? In the document they describe a profile using XML - very simple. But where does the profile reside in the application? Is the profile just an agreement between the client and server applications, or is it coded into the BT stack somewhere...

Comment: I don't think they're written into the stack - the whole idea as far as I can tell is that devices can advertise which profiles they support and then apps can connect to profiles that they know about (either standard or home-made ones). Check out the CoreBluetooth framework, which is the iOS API you'd use to acces the devices: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html It seems to map to the xml from before (UUID's left and right :)